# neovim + deoplete: how to enable 'timers'

Tags: timer, neovim

I want to make deoplete autocompletion suggestions pop up faster, that calls for setting

```
g:deoplete#auto_complete_delay
```

help says this requires `+timers` support. How do I enable this `timers` in config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+timers` is a compile-time feature of Vim that is available in Neovim from v0.1.5 onwards.

Compile-time features cannot be dynamically toggled, they are either there or not. `+timers` is an optional feature in Vim but non-optional in Neovim. So if you are using Neovim 0.1.5+, you already have the feature active. In fact, deoplete would not work properly without it.

You can verify that the feature is enabled: `:echo has('timers')`. If the result is `1`, it's there, `0` mean it is not.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as the correct one to let others know it's been solved? Thanks.